# Extracting and printing substring(based on delimiter or pattern) from key value pair in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have a document in mongoDB with key value pairs in which we have two columns "_id" and "value" column which looks like below:

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53cf9048b6e9e884602db85f"),

```
     "value" : "Security ID:\t\tS-1-0-0\tAccount Name:\t\tKanav Narula\tAccount Domain:\t\tINDIA\t
```

}

Now we want to execute a query on value field. 
We want to extract Account Name and Account Domain from value field defined in the above document.
Expected output:

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53cf9048b6e9e884602db85f"),

```
    "value" : "Security ID:\t\tS-1-0-0\tAccount Name:\t\tKanav Narula\tAccount Domain:\t\tINDIA\t,

    "Account Name" : Kanav Narula,

    "Account Domain" : INDIA
```

}

can anyone suggest ways to perform this activity in mongoDB.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it searchable, the components of the Value string should have been separate fields, otherwise, Value is just a large string.  The schema is wrong for what you are trying to do. Did you port it from Redis or some other key/value store?  MongoDB is not a key/value store, you need to rethink your use case in a new light so to speak.

Comment: We have imported the data from MySQL. we have \t(tab) separator in above large value string.                                           Can we use "\t" as delimiter to make data in key value pairs.

Comment: The string is a tab-separated value. When you insert it, you need to split on the tabs to get the key-value pairs, which you can then insert as part of the document. I'm not sure how you are doing the insertions so I can't say how you should execute the split, but in whatever language you are using there should be good CSV libraries that can handle tab-separated values.